# Can you compute rank r factorization of a n*n matrix in time O(n^2 r)?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra, svd

I am wondering if you can compute the SVD/eigenvectors of a rank r matrix of size n*n in time O(n^2 r)? My understanding is that standard eigenvector computations involve bringing matrix into Hesseberg form which costs O(n^3) operations.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [Halko-Martinsson-Tropp](http://arxiv.org/abs/0909.4061)

Comment: Thanks. I found that Rank Revealing QR can factorize some matrices in O(n^2 r) time, but has worst case complexity of O(n^3). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RRQR_factorization

Answer (score 0):

If the matrix is real symmetric (hermitian) then there are spectrum splitting methods that can find the spectrum in O(n r^2). I am sure that can be extended to SVD calculations also.
I don't have the reference handy but if you want I can look it up.

BTW do you have an upper bound on $r$?

Comment: Let us say r=10. Can you find the singular vectors in  O(n^2) time complexity. If so can you please tell me by which algorithm?

Comment: btw please forgive my typo of  )(n r^2) instead of O(n^2 r) (quadratic)

Comment: I was trying to locate it without too much success. The idea is to find a value $t$, so that there are no more than $10$ singular values greater than $m$. Once you have that, then isolating them is just an extension of Lanczos algorithm. Can you give me like 10 minutes. I will reply one way or another.

Comment: Here is a reference that is based on Lanczos algorithm: JOURNAL  OF  COMPUTATIONAL  PHYSICS  17,  87-94  (1975): he Iterative  Calculation  of a Few of
the Lowest  Eigenvalues  and Corresponding  Eigenvectors  of
Large Real-Symmetric  Matrices, by Davidson is a good starting point. Note in physics, the smallest eigenvalues/singular values are of interest. You can easily adapt it to find the large one. The key method is the Lanczos algorithm.

Comment: Great. I will take a look at it. Thanks again :)